# How to reuse dynamoDB table

Tags: typescript, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I use aws cdk to deploy a stack that contains a dynamoDB table. For each deploy of my stack, CloudFormation creates a new table and links it to my lambda function. I want to know how I can reuse an existing table, without the need to create a new one if it was already created for this stack (to avoid migrating my record to a new instance of the dynamoDB table).

Here is my code:

```js
const table = new Table(stack, id, {
    billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
    partitionKey: {
        name: "id",
        type: AttributeType.STRING,
    },
    removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.SNAPSHOT,
});
```

I previously tried to use `Table.fromTableName`, but I cloudn't link my lambda function to the table...

Here is the code I tried:

```js
let myTable: Table; // my table
let lambdaFunction: Function = new Function(...); // my function

// table creation
try {
    myTable = Table.fromTableName(stack, tableId, name);
} catch (_) {
    myTable = new Table(stack, id, {
        billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
        partitionKey: {
            name: "id",
            type: AttributeType.STRING,
        },
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.SNAPSHOT,
    });
}

//referencing the table in my lambda function via env
lambdaFunction.addEnvironment("TABLE_NAME", myTable.tableName);
```

When the lambda tries to access the table a `ResourceNotFound` exception is thrown.

Any ideas?

As well I heard that if I use the same `tableName` in `new Table(...)` dynamoDB will return me the existing table without creating a new one, but I don't know if it's true...
Does someone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rechecked the matter, the answer actually is to use constant constructor ids along with constant resource names.

From this [blog](https://betterdev.blog/understanding-logical-ids-in-cdk-and-cloudformation/):

> But as we discussed earlier, replacing resources is likely not the best thing to do in the first place. So to prevent it, we just don’t modify the CDK Construct IDs.

So what I did is to give hard-coded constructor ids, along with hard-coded table name, that wouldn't be changed. This preserve the logical ID of the resource to CloudFormation would identify it and prevent deletion and re-creation of the resource.

Note that you need to take a different approach if you are using nested constructors, as detailed in the [blog](https://betterdev.blog/understanding-logical-ids-in-cdk-and-cloudformation/):

> CDK generates the Logical IDs based on the full Construct “path”. With nested Constructs, IDs of all “higher” Constructs are used to create the unique Logical ID. [...] So even if we don’t change the Construct IDs, moving Constructs into other Constructs changes generated Logical IDs. This is what often happens during development or refactoring.

So, as said here is the fixed code:

```js
myTable = new Table(stack, "MyTableConstructor", {
       tableName: "MyTable",
       billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
       partitionKey: {
           name: "id",
           type: AttributeType.STRING,
       },
       removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.SNAPSHOT,
});
```

This will work with an existing table, no need to use `Table.fromTableName` to import it :)

So, it wasn't linked to the removal policy of the table or the use of `Table.fromTableName`, only that the logical ID was messed up...

Comment: Ah, the question never mentioned that your `id` was being regenerated each time. If it's not, you don't need to specify `tableName` at all. And to help you get intuition behind construct IDs - think of them as your resource names. So "MyTable" would be a better ID than "MyTableConstructor".

Comment: Actually I had a fixed id value for the constructor, yet CloudFormation continued to generate the resource name each time... only when the logical id was the same (which is generated based on the resource name + the constructor id) CloudFormation could recognize the resource and then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change retention policy of the table, as a `Snapshot` will not retain your table and data in a usable manner. Explicitly defining a table name will also allow you to easily import the table again, without having to understand what CDK named the table for you.

```
removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
tableName: 'MyLovelyTable',
```

Then `Table.fromTableName` will work, as long as you provide the correct table name from the [`Table` interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.ITable.html).

```
const importedTable = dynamodb.Table.fromTableName(
  this,
  'table-from-name-id',
  'MyLovelyTable',
);
```

If you create the stack often, and don't often know what the tableName is, then every time you change the table you can store the name in Parameter Store and retrieve it when needed.